# Find normal subgroup of the following group

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Is the group $G$ given by

$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \alpha &\beta \\0& 1 &\gamma\\0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}:\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \Bbb R\right\}$$

simple?

My try:
Obviously $G$ is a subgroup of $\text{SL}_n(\Bbb R)$

I tried with matrices like 
$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \alpha &\alpha \\0& 1 &\alpha\\0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}:$\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \Bbb R\right\}$$

but they did not help.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not simple. The matrices of the form$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&\alpha\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$($\alpha\in\mathbb R$) form a normal subgroup.

Comment: This represents the center $Z(G)$ of the given group $G$ and centers are normal.

Answer (score 5):

Inverse of \begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & x & y \\ 
   0 &1 &z \\ 
   0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
is given by 
$\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & -x & xz-y \\ 
      0 & 1 & -z \\ 
    0 & 0 & 1 
 \end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$

Denote the center of this group by $Z\big(G\big)=\left\{\, \begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & 0 & y \\ 
   0 &1 &0 \\ 
   0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} \quad \middle| \quad \text{ for any } y\in \mathbb{R} \, \right \}.$

Now show that $Z(G)$ is normal in $G$.

Let $A\in G, B\in Z(G)$ be any arbitrary element. Now show that $ABA^{-1}\in Z(G)$

$G$ is also known as Heisenberg Group(in our case over $\mathbb{R}$

---

**Question by OP in comments**: How to find $Z(G)$

Let $M=\begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & x & y \\ 
   0 &1 &z \\ 
   0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\in Z(G)$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & a & b \\ 
   0 &1 &c \\ 
   0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$ be an arbitrary element in $G$. By definition we have $AM=MA$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & a & b \\ 
   0 &1 &c \\ 
   0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & x & y \\ 
   0 &1 &z \\ 
   0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & x & y \\ 
   0 &1 &z \\ 
   0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & a & b \\ 
   0 &1 &c \\ 
   0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Take the product.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & x+a & y+az+b \\ 
   0 &1 &z+c \\ 
   0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & a+x & b+cx+y \\ 
   0 &1 &c+z \\ 
   0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Since $A$ was arbitrarily chosen. As a particular case,

Take $a=0 , c=1$ you get $x=0$

Take $a=1,c=0$ you get $z=0$

Comment: Explain the down votes please.

Comment: No idea. Perhaps because it is more or less identical to the earlier answer? I've upvoted it anyway.

Comment: I was writing the answer when other user posted his answer. It took me some time to write matrices in latex. @DerekHolt

Comment: But is not $Z(G)=\{I\}$?Did You check?

Comment: @Learnmore What I have written is correct.

Comment: But how do you know that Z(G) is not trivial?I doubt it,can you show what Z(G) is actually

Comment: @Learnmore You start with some matrix $M$ and assume it is in the center then take any arbitrary element in $G$ say $A$ and try to solve $AM=MA$. You get some conditions on elements.    I know $Z(G)$ is non trivial because I calculated the center and found out that it is non trivial. Also this is a very famous group know as Heisenberg Group and has lot of applications in applied and physical sciences. I knew it beforehand.

Comment: @Learnmore Since you are asking I will add the calculation part in the body.

Comment: @Learnmore Have a look at the calculation. Thanks and Cheers!!

Comment: I did a calculation mistake ,so I got it trivial,thanks for helping,you deserve a +1

Answer (score 2):

The map below is a homomorphism $G \to \text{SL}_2(\Bbb R)$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \alpha &\beta \\0& 1 &\gamma\\0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \alpha \\0& 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefore, its kernel is a normal subgroup of $G$.

The kernel is the set of matrices in $G$ with $\alpha=0$, and so is a nontrivial proper subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Nice approach (+1)